ChromaDB: download embedding in advance during package installation
Is there an option to install the Chroma DB Python pip package (chromadb) together with download of embedding (e.g. all-MiniLM-L6-v2) instead of downloading the embedding on demand?

Danny Varod did you find a way to achieve the above? Thanks

@RmR, sorry no.

Thanks Danny Varod. Check this issue I posted in chromadb github that was responded by Tazarov (a contributor to the repo) which provides the solution. https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/2761

@RmR solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79282075/38368

If you download the repo for the embedding model, you can then pass the path to the root of the repo instead of the name of the model to SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name)
from chromadb.utils.embedding_functions.sentence_transformer_embedding_function import (
    SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction
)

chromadb_embedding = SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_path)

A similar solution works for llamaindex:
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding

llamaindex_embedding = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_path)

and for directive usage of the model for ranking:
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

embedding = SentenceTransformer(model_path)

It's a shame you can pass the HuggingFaceEmbedding object directly to chromadb and llamaindex, as they create this object anyway.
